# ENOENT, no such file or directory but file exists

Tags: jquery, node.js, intel-edison

I'm trying to build something using NodeJs on Intel Edison. I am using the plugin: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload and the NodeJS Server side part.

However, I keep getting

```
fs.js:543
  return binding.rename(pathModule._makeLong(oldPath),
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/root/db/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node/tmp/8fa2946958c04ad8cb6def7b1e9dab01'
    at Object.fs.renameSync (fs.js:543:18)
    at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (/home/root/db/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node/server.js:248:16)
    at IncomingForm.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at /home/root/db/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:228:12
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (/home/root/db/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node/node_modules/formidable/lib/file.js:70:5)
    at WriteStream.g (events.js:180:16)
    at WriteStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:360:12)
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:280:5)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:270:7)
```

Whenever I try to upload something.The problem is that the file `/home/root/db/node_modules/blueimp-file-upload-node/tmp/8fa2946958c04ad8cb6def7b1e9dab01` does indeed exist and I *guess* that I also have the permissions right in the folder.

I tried several things, but I am really stuck here, I cannot understand how can I get around this.

Answer (score 0):

After the error, is the file there by the old name or the new name?  (I've had cases where two threads were inadvertenly started, and the second found the file already gone).  Does the target directory exist?  Any typos?

Here's what the linux manpage says about rename:

ENOENT The link named by oldpath does not exist; or, a directory component in  newpath
does not exist; or, oldpath or newpath is an empty string.

Edit: this is a nodejs bug, it reports that the source file is missing when it's actually the destination directory that's the problem.  To reproduce from the command line:

```
% touch /tmp/file.txt
% node -p 'fs = require("fs"); fs.renameSync("/tmp/file.txt", "/nonesuch/file.txt");'
```

it prints:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/tmp/file.txt'
    at Object.fs.renameSync (fs.js:548:18)
    at [eval]:1:24
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at evalScript (node.js:536:25)
    at startup (node.js:80:7)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Edit: here's a possible way to wrapper renameSync() to fix this (untested!)

```
var _origRename = fs.renameSync;
fs.renameSync = function(from, to) {
    try { _origRename(from, to) }
    catch (err) {
        if (err.stack.indexOf('ENOENT') < 0) throw err;
        try { fs.statSync(from) } catch (err2) { throw err }
        throw new Error("ENOENT, no such file or directory '" + to "'");
    }
}
```

Comment: File is there by the old name and the target directory doesn't exist (but that should not be a problem since it's not reading in the first place). No typos.

Comment: aha!  it's reproducible from the command line, see the edit above -- node reports that the source is not found even when the problem is with the destination

Comment: Yups. :( Any idea how to get around it?

Comment: should be easy to wrapper the rename / renameSync commands to try/catch the rename and test the source file on error.  Easy, but a pain.  The can be wrappered and replaced in fact, so your whole app would benefit from the fix.

Comment: see the edit above for a simple wrapper to renameSync

Comment: This was driving me crazy! I didn't think to check the destination path.